# Is it possible to have functions run off the string within a variable rather than the variable name itself in C++?

Tags: c++, string, variables, naming

Its kind of hard to describe, but I'm basically asking whether or not I can have a function calling `myString` and actually have the string within get put into the function.

My code so far is:

```
for(uint n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
  int r = n * n;
  std::string R = std::to_string(n);
  std::string currentSquared = ("Squared" + R);
  int currentSquared.c_str() = r;
}
```

I know it's wrong I'd like the output to be a set of variables like:

```
Squared1 = 1, Squared4 = 16.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what are `Squared1 `and `Squared4` ?

Comment: Variable names in c++ are strictly compile time. You can't create variable names from run-time strings like this. You could just use a `vector` to store the data.

Comment: `("Squared" + R)` if using ASCII is far after "Squared"

Comment: you cannot have vars likes that

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You can however use templates to get something like `Squared<4> = 16`.

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map),  [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: @BennyK Template arguments are also compile-time concepts. You cannot use them with a variable like `int n;`, that would boil down to the same problem as OP is having.

Comment: as said by @PaulMcKenzie what is your *real* problem/question ?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve. Take a step back and tell us what you are _actually_ trying to achieve.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That depends on the origin of `5`. If it is a runtime variable it's possible to use `std::vector` with a similar syntax

Comment: ***Squared1 = 1, Squared4 = 16.*** instead of this you probably want an array. `squared[0] =1; squared[3] = 16;` Notice in c++ array indices start at 0 not 1. Also if you don't know the size of the array before the calculation the dynamic array in c++ is std::vector

Answer (score 3):

You can take the help of `std::unordered_map` to create keys and gather data from them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main(void) {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, int> variables;

  // Initializing the map with their respective required keys
  for (int i{1}; i <= 10; i++)
    variables["Squared" + std::to_string(i)] = i * i;

  // Displaying one of the initialized key
  std::cout << variables["Squared4"];

  return 0;
}
```

As a result, it'll display your desired output:

```
16    // 'Squared4' key holds (4 * 4) = 16
```

Comment: +1 Although this solves the problem the OP asked for and it will work it's probably not really what is needed. More likely the OP really wants the other solutions.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't create arbitrary variables like you described, besides variable names are used during compilation and debugging, if you compile without debug symbols they disappear completely.

What you need here is to use an appropriate data structure to hold your data, instead of creating more variables to work with, you can read more about standard library containers [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

I would suggest using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) in your case.

```cpp
std::vector<int> numbers{};
numbers.reserve(10);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    numbers.push_back(i * i);
}

std::cout << "Numbers squared:\n";
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << i << '*' << i << " = " << numbers[i] << '\n';
}
```

`std::vector` will take care of storing all the data for you, and should be your 1st choice as a container most of the time.

If you would like a dictionary that would allow you to index element with let's say `std::string` or `const char*`, you could also use a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {

    vector<string> mystring;
    for (int n = 0; n < 5; ++n) {
        int squared = n * n;
        string str_squared = to_string(squared);
        mystring.push_back(str_squared);
   }

    for (int j = 0; j < mystring.size(); ++j) {
        cout << mystring[j] << endl;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

I would try to store my strings in a container. In this instance,  I used a vector. This allows me to have a set of strings, that are n squared. To display them I can iterate through my vector in the for loop. Not sure if this is what you were trying to achieve from your question.